# codeigniter: loading variables and view from within model

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm building an image uploading script (for the first time) in Codeigniter and the way I have it is that if the image upload form gets validated it performs the following code in a model:

```
public function upload($id) //function to handle the initial image upload before crop
{
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width']     = 75;
    $config['height']   = 50;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

    $this->image_lib->resize();

    $config['upload_path'] = 'images/uploads/temp/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $file_data = $this->upload->data();

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload() )//the default parameter of do_upload() is 'userfile' (meaning the name of the form input) 
    {
        $error = '<p>Upload failed!</p> <p>Please make sure the image is in a .jpg, .gif or .png format and that it\'s no larger than 1028 x 768 pixels in dimension. Also it can\'t be more than 2MBs in size. If this problem persists, please contact <a href="mailto:webmaster@dreamsy.org">webmaster@dreamsy.org</a>.</p>';

        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
        redirect(base_url().'community/upload_image');
    }
    else
    {
        $image_path = base_url().'images/uploads/temp/'.$file_name;
        //$data = array( 'upload_data' => $this->upload->data() );

        //$this->load->view('community/upload_success');
        $this->load->helper('form', 'url');
        $vars['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $vars['$image_path'] = $image_path;
        $vars['$file_data'] = $file_data;
        $this->load->vars($vars); 
        $this->template->write_view('content', 'community/upload_success');
        $this->template->render();
    }
}>template->render(); //template library
```

But when I call the variables that are loaded (via load->vars()) they don't get loaded and when the page loads I get "undefined variable" errors. I suspect it's not possible to pass variables from a model to the view even when the view is loaded from within the model as I have done above. Or maybe I'm just doing something incorrectly (as I'm a bit of a n00b).

Would you even take this route? Would it make more sense to pass the variables to the controller and then to load the view from the controller? Or something else I haven't considered at all? lol

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

*edit:
I also have the $image_path variable inside of an

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would you even take this route? Would it make more sense to pass the variables to the controller and then to load the view from the controller? Or something else I haven't considered at all?

Yeah, generally speaking it is *somewhat* accepted to have your views talk directly to the model and vice versa but only when using a presentation layer. In the case of CI, I think it's best to have all the data loaded in from your controller to your view when you render the view like this:

```
$this->load->view('your-view', $data);
```

To pass the vars from the model to the controller you can call methods on your model like this:

```
// Your_Model is the class name of your model
// your_model is the variable name it gets injected into
$this->load->model('Your_Model','your_model');

$data['some_data'] = $this->your_model->get_some_data();
```

To define those getters in your model, you define a function like this:

```
function get_some_data()
{
    return $this->some_data;
}
```

That way you create an API into your data, and you can have the getter retrieve whatever you will need in the format you will need it in.

Comment: And how would you pass the variables from the model to the controller?

Comment: Have a read up on view_data here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: So I load the model function I currently have now but instead of loading the view there I have it return an array with the data I want to call in the view and then use the controller to load the view and the array?

Comment: Precisely. This way the model is only data and the view is only view.

Comment: Can I have an array of the variables I want called in the view from the model to the controller by saying: "return $vars"? Cuz that's what I tried and it is telling me that the variable is undefined even though I have a load->vars($vars) line in my controller.

Comment: my example doesn't use load vars. please try the code from the example or read up on view data like leopold says.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for your help. It was a real life saver. Literally, . . . someone could have died, but he's safe, . . . for now. mwahahahahaha

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the line:
    $this->load->vars($vars);
is where you want to load your view, then it should be:
    $this->load->view('nameofview', $vars);

Comment: I'm using a template library instead of load->view which should be doing the same thing anyway.